# Which all licenses refrain user from removing the “license notice”?

Tags: open-source, licensing

Can someone tell me which all licenses restrict a user from removing the license notification at the top of a file?
Case:
Some JavaScript files have sections like this:

> “/*  RequireJS 0.26.0 Copyright (c) 2010-2011, The Dojo Foundation All
>   Rights Reserved.  Available via the MIT or new BSD license.  see:
>   http://github.com/jrburke/requirejs for details
>   */”

During compression is it fair to remove this?

Comment: If you want to make the file smaller, this doesn't seem exactly like low-hanging fruit.  If it is impossible that the files will ever be redistributed, you can probably do whatever you want with them.  I would be extremely wary of removing a license statement from a file which could somehow end up in somebody else's hands sometime before the heat death of the universe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't run into any problems removing the license from the top if it doesn't say you can't.  A minifier will remove the comment too.

Just don't redistribute the code without the license.

Answer (score 1):

Both the MIT and BSD licenses (the two options that header indicates) require that the license is kept intact. You should not remove it during compression.